# monitor a date field in first entity and before the date create a record in another entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365

This is the scenario: I have two entities
Tasks entity which has a end date field and the second entity called notifications . I need a technique to monitor the end date in the task and before 5 days of the end date create a record in notification entity.

How can I apply this please  in dynamics 365 without using wait condition because it consumes the server?

Comment: In classic workflows, you could be using a Timeout instead of Wait, which does not consume resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely this can be performed and for our developer's sake Microsoft built and provided a very nice cloud service called [Power Automate (Cloud Flows).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/)

Power automate is very powerful and can perform a lot, as it has I don't know number of connections to different system and definitely CDS is out of box

For your use case you need [flow on a scheduled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks)

[Then you need CDS current env connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/)

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to have a scheduled job, like Power Automate flow or Task scheduler to run console app or SSIS + Kingswaysoft to run once everyday for fetching all the Tasks satisfying that end date condition, iterate through them and create a record in notification entity.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a Power Automate flow that checks if the 5 days are up based on the required date parameters. If they are create the record. Schedule this flow to run daily at a specific time.